# How can I see the number of times a file I hosted on Mega and shared the URL got downloaded?

Tags: mega

I hosted a file on Mega and shared the URL: How can I see the number of times it got downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to see the number of times it got downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

Look at your transfer quota under `settings -> advanced` to get a rough idea